# AngularJS adding Dependency issue

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, ionic-framework, dependency-management, uislider

I want to use angular-slider module in my project, I downloaded git from https://github.com/venturocket/angular-slider and added the angular-slider.js and angular-slider.css in my project and included the link in the index page like this

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/angular-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script> 
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-slider.js"></script>
```

and added the 'uiSlider' as dependency in app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['uiSlider', ...]);
```

As soon as I add 'uiSlider' as dependency in app.js the app does not work. There are no error messages in the console. I tried adding another module in the same way but the same problem occurs.

Is there anything wrong with the way I am including the module in my project? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the script tag containing a reference to your module? It must be below angular-slider.js Also the link you provided says the module is deprecated and links to other repos that may work better, have you tried those?

Comment: I tried using another module also, but the same error prevails and isnt angular-slider.js the reference to the module ?

Comment: That's the reference to uiSlider module yes, i'm asking where is the script reference to your `app` module?

Comment: Its right below angular-slider.js. like this -  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>

Comment: Not to be a pain, but why not use the Ionic range component? The docs for this module claim it is not maintained and could very well just not work in most recent versions of Angular.

Comment: Is there a dependency manager for JS, such as Maven? That would really help.

Comment: I need a dual knob slider, which is not present in the ionic range component. And as I already mentioned I tried importing other modules also, but the problem remains

Comment: Also, I have changed the mdoule link in the above question to show that I am not using a deprecated module